# Front Panel Jack Also Getting Detected As Speakers

Tags: windows-10, audio, speakers, headphones, realtek-hd-audio

I just recently installed realtek audio drivers on my windows 10 PC and since then my PC is only detecting my speakers. I have my speakers plugged into the rear panel. When I plug my headphones into the front panel, sound does come out of it but it also comes out the speakers at the same time.

I went into Sound settings and playback devices, and found out that my headphones are getting recognized as part of my speakers:

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: Run *Realtek Audio Console*, click *Realtek Digital Output*, then on *Device advanced settings*. Under "Connector Retasking", see if you can set the "Front Panel" to "Headphones".

Comment: @harrymc Thanks, I managed to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I managed to fix it by separating the outputs in Realtek HD audio Manager:

- Open Realtek Hd Audio Manager
- Click on Device Advanced Settings in the top right corner, in blue
- Under Playback Devices, click on "Make front and rear output devices playback two different audio streams simultaneously"
- Click Ok

This Should fix the issue.

For anyone struggling with the instruction, here is a video:
[Headphones Show Up As Speakers (FIX)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nIb-kRHgE4M)